# Calculate new product value from known product, distance and shift

Tags: algebra-precalculus, products

I have $p_1 = xy$ and the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $d = |x-y|$.

I don’t know the values of $x$ and $y$ but I know the product and distance between them, I want to get new product $p_2$ after moving or shifting $x$ and $y$ by value $s$.
I can solve it using quadratic equation based on equations  $xy=p_1$ and $|x-y|=d$ but is there a function of $(p_1, d,s)$ to get new value $p_2$ without quadratic equation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE, please use MathJax to edit the formulae for easier reading

Comment: If I saw it during review I may have edited  as under.                                            1,2 are points along x-axis with known coordinates x1 and x2. I have $ p1 = x1 x2 $ and the separation distance between them is $ d = |x1-x2| $.

I don’t know the values of $x1$ and $x2$ but I know  p1 and d. 

Next  I  want to get new product $p_2$ after moving or shifting $x1$ and $x2$ each by value $s$ along x-axis.

I can solve it using quadratic equation based on above equations but is there a function of $(p_1, d,s)$ to get new value $ p_2 $ without using a quadratic equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**

You are looking for
$$
(x-s)(y-s) = xy - s(x+y) + s^2.
$$
Since $xy$ and $s$ are known, the only thing you need is $x+y$. To get it, note that
$$
(x+y)^2 = (x-y)^2 + 4xy,
$$
and again both items on the RHS are known...

**Warning** The quadraticity of the last equation will allow for both positive and negative values of $x+y$

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.